# argparse python problem with initializing functions

Tags: python, argparse

why is my program jumping straight to the else block in the while loop (getting "You've chosen unavailable option! Exiting..." statement) instead of initializing the functions when user is prompted to choose an option? No matter if I type 'Q', 'q', 'Z', 'z', 'X', 'x' or any other letter. This is my first time working with argparse module so your understanding is appreciated.

```
import sys, argparse

from functions import get_expired_OINs, get_OINs, download_certs


def initialize(choice):

    print("What would you like to do today? \n"
        "Press X to check all expired certificates \n"
        "Press Z to only download certificates for selected OIN numbers \n"
        "or press Q to exit. \n"
        "")

    while True:
        choice = input("My choice: ")
    
        if choice.upper() == args.Q:
            sys.exit()
        elif choice.upper() == args.X:
            get_expired_OINs() 
            download_certs()
            break
        elif choice.upper() == args.Z:
            get_OINs()
            download_certs()
            break
        else:
            print("You've chosen unavailable option! Exiting...")
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
                                    
    parser.add_argument(
        '-q',
        type=str, 
        dest='Q',
        help='To quit the program'
        )    
    parser.add_argument(
        '-x',
        type=str, 
        dest='X',
        help='To check for expired AS certificates'
        )     
    parser.add_argument(
        '-z',
        type=str, 
        dest='Z',
        help='To check AS certificates as needed'
        ) 
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    # print(args)  < -- here I get object: Namespace(Q=None, X=None, Z=None)
    initialize(args)
```

When the while loop is changed to the below:

```
while True:
        choice = input("My choice: ")
        
        if choice.upper() == 'Q':
            sys.exit()
        elif choice.upper() == 'X':
            get_expired_OINs() 
            download_certs()
            break
        elif choice.upper() == 'Z':
            get_OINs()
            download_certs()
            break
        else:
            print("You've chosen unavailable option! Exiting...")
            sys.exit()
```

the program works as expected, but I would like to tie it with the argparse module.

Comment: You don't appear to be passing any command-line arguments when you run the program. That said, if you are passing `-q` ,`-x`, etc, you probably want to use that value instead of `choice.upper()`, not instead of the hard-coded `Q`/`X`/`Z`.

Comment: The obvious explanation is that `args.Q` is not simply the letter "Q".

Comment: Argparse is not a replacement for input, especially in a loop. Argparse is used to parse command line arguments, not request or parse input from a user.

Comment: Suggested reading ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/53341

Comment: What are you trying to do with `argparse`?  As defined it  sets three attributes, Without commandline values those 3 values are all `None`, as your `print(args)` shows.  With commandline values (do you know what those are?), one or more  will be replaced with a user defined string (not necessarily the same letter).  Why are you asking for user `input`, and trying to match that to `args.X` etc?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to use `argparse` to replace the call to `input`. Your three options should all set the same destination, just with a different constant. When you run the program, you must supply one of the three options. (You probably want to supply *exactly* one of three; you should look at creating a mutually exclusive group. See the `argparse` documentation for details.)

(Note: there is no reason to have a `-q` option, as opposed to simply not running the program in the first place.)

```
import sys, argparse

from functions import get_expired_OINs, get_OINs, download_certs


def initialize(choice):
    
    print("What would you like to do today? \n"
          "Press X to check all expired certificates \n"
          "Press Z to only download certificates for selected OIN numbers \n"
          "or press Q to exit. \n"
          "")
    
    choice = args.choice
        
    if choice == 'Q':
        sys.exit()
    elif choice = 'X':
        get_expired_OINs() 
        download_certs()
    elif choice == 'Z':
        get_OINs()
        download_certs()
    else:
        print("You've chosen unavailable option! Exiting...")
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
                                    
    parser.add_argument(
        '-q',
        action='store_const',
        const='Q',
        dest='choice',
        help='To quit the program'
        )    
    parser.add_argument(
        '-x',
        action='store_const',
        const='X',
        dest='choice',
        help='To check for expired AS certificates'
        )     
    parser.add_argument(
        '-z',
        action='store_const',
        const='Z',
        dest='choice',
        help='To check AS certificates as needed'
        ) 
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    initialize(args)
```

Comment: `while True:` makes no sense in this context. Because the op mistakenly wants argparse to repeatedly take (and parse) input from the user. (The print statement also makes it clear that the op doesn't want argparse for command line arguments.)

Comment: True about the loop. I think showing the OP what `argparse` *is* suitable for is useful, though, if only to convince them that `argparse` is not solving the problem they think it does.

Comment: Now you have `break` without a loop. And `else:` indentation is wrong.